# How do I mock whatwg-fetch for testing in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component that fetches some data in its `componentDidMount` function.  The function that fetches the data is in `fetch-data.js`.  I am trying to test this component, and want to mock the fetched data.  I am trying to follow this link in mocking the `fetch` function for tests: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

I have my `__mocks__` folder adjacent to my `node_modules` folder:

```
...
node_modules
__mocks__
└── whatwg-fetch.js
...
```

my whatwg-fetch.js mock looks like this:

```
const whatwgFetch = jest.genMockFromModule('whatwg-fetch');
whatwgFetch.fetch = (url) => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ ok: true }));

module.exports = whatwgFetch;
```

However, when I run tests, I still get this error:

```
 RUNS  src/scenes/Home/Home.spec.js
 myproject/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:20
  throw err;
  ^

TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (/Local/Users/john/Documents/js/react/haiku/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js:436:16)
```

The XHR request in question is not going to a third party, but is a local URL (`fetch('/my/local/file')`), if that makes any difference.

edit: It seems like even if there is nothing in the component tests, I get the same error.  Everything is commented out in `MyComponent.spec.js` and it seems to still try and make network requests.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I had installed `jest-fetch-mock` and added these lines to my `src/setupTests.js`:

```
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock'); 
fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ testing: true }));
```

and now the tests run.

Answer (score 3):

If we want to mock fetch in only one file then we could test it by spying on the window fetch and give our implementation (mock one) and test it.

```
//needs fetch polyfill to be loaded in ths test file
import 'whatwg-fetch';

let windowFetchSpy;
beforeEach(() => {
  //spyon read only window fetch
  windowFetchSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch');
});

afterEach(() => {
  // store back the original implementation of window fetch
  windowFetchSpy = jest.mockRestore();
})

test('window fetch',() => {
 // set the behavior of mock fetch (either resolve or reject)
  windowFetchSpy.mockResolvedValueOnce({
    ok: true,
    json: async () => ({success: true}),
  });
  

  expect(windowFetchFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```